# How do I exit a "do while" statement

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub FindValue()

Dim firstAddress As String
Dim Expense As String
Dim rRange As Range
Dim FirstrngFnd As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer

Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
    "D:\My Documents\Excel Files\AA Credit Card\1008.xlsx"        'A worksheet with several columns - Column G (Column 7) is a list of "expenses".  
Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
    "D:\My Documents\Excel Files\Credit Card Analysis.xlsx"       'A worksheet with "expenses" listed in random order in Column A (Column1)
Windows("Credit Card Analysis.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate

Expense = Application.InputBox("Select the required expense from Column A")     'Pick an "expense" from a list in Column A

'Open the first file in the first folder
Windows("1008.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate

'Establish the first and last rows in Column A (which contain a list of dates by increasing date): required to establish the search range
Set rRange = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If IsDate(rCell) Then
            rCell(2, 1).Select
    Exit For
        End If
    Next rCell

x = (ActiveCell.Row - 1)                          'This finds the FIRST row in the file with a date in it
y = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row            'This finds the LAST row in the file with a date in it
My_Workbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name                                               'Holds the current Workbook name

'Move over to the "analysis" column (G) (Column 7)
With Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(x, 7), Cells(y, 7))
    Set FirstrngFnd = .Find(Expense, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)          'Finds the first occurrence of "expense"
        If Not FirstrngFnd Is Nothing Then                                      'if the "expense" isn't listed then goto Line400
            firstAddress = FirstrngFnd.Address
        Do           'DO WHATEVER IS REQUIRED IN THIS SECTION: FROM "DO" TO "Set FirstrngFnd = .FindNext(FirstrngFnd)"
            z = FirstrngFnd.Row
            FirstrngFnd.Value = "Mike"        'IF YOU OMIT THIS LINE THEN ALL THE VALUES REMAIN AT "expense", SO THE PROGRAM JUST GOES ROUND (AND ROUND) AGAIN.
            Set FirstrngFnd = .FindNext(FirstrngFnd)
        Loop While Not FirstrngFnd Is Nothing
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

If I remove the line  "FirstrngFnd.Value = "Mike" then the values in Golumn G never change so when the program gets to the end of the file, it just goes round again.

How can I get it to recognise it's been through the file once, and to move on?

Comment: Do you mean just `Exit Do`?

Comment: What does your VB reference say? When you studied a list of commands/keywords, did any of them come close to suiting your purpose? Which were they?

Comment: Your syntax does not look correct, here's a short tutorial on `Do While` loops...https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_do_while_loop.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please, modify:

```
Loop While Not FirstrngFnd Is Nothing
```

in this way:

```
Loop While Not FirstrngFnd Is Nothing And FirstrngFnd.Address <> firstAddress
```

Comment: Pretty sure VBA does not "short circuit" `And`'ed tests, so `FirstrngFnd.Address` will error when `FirstrngFnd` is `Nothing`

Comment: `FirstrngFnd` will never be `Nothing` which is ensured with `If Not FirstrngFnd Is Nothing Then`. It is just redundant.

Comment: @VBasic2008: Then, place a complain to Microsoft. They suggest [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) this way of `FindNext` looping when the found cell value is not modified...

Comment: @Tim Williams: With all respect, this one of the Microsoft's recommended way. I had such existential questions on this aspect, but finding here Microsoft's "Range.FindNext method" definition examples, I thought that they maybe know something I missed... It's true, they recommend this way for cases when the found cell value is not modified in the loop and what I suggested may not help... :-)

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood the question. I understood that OP is trying to get rid of the line `FirstrngFnd.Value = "Mike"`. Redundant doesn't mean its wrong, it means it's not necessary. You can easily prove Tim Williams' point with the lines `Dim rng As Range: Debug.Print rng.Address`. One must not forget that both conditions will be evaluated. BTW you can just use `Do` : `Loop` (without `While` or `Until`) and add two nested `If` statements before `Loop`, the inner one containing `Exit Do`.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you for all your comments, however unless I'm missing something the solution recommended by @FaneDuru appears to work perfectly. The programme searches to find each cell containing the "expense" (Doesn't now do anything with it, because I've removed the operative line), gets to the end of the file and stops. (Although it doesn't actually "stop" until it's started the second loop through the file and  "FirstrngFnd.Address <> firstAddress ". I'm pretty sure that's what I want it to do, although the actual "Do" is going to be a bit more complicated than simply substitute one cell

Comment: one cell value for another. But I couldn't do anything until I could get to recognise the end of the file. Thanks again. P.S. @VBasic2008 - "FirstrngFnd" IS nothing IF the test doesn't find ANY occurrences of "expense" - hence not redundant (I think??)

Comment: @mikesingleton: So, it is not very clear for me: Did my answer solve your problem? Is it something else not working as you need?

Comment: The `Hide_Columns` example at the posted MS link is bad, in the sense it *can* error when nothing is found.  You might or might not see that error, depending on whether your last previous use of Find specified `lookin:=xlValues` (which will *not* find values in hidden cells) or `lookin:=xlFormulas` (which *does* find values in hidden cells).  The example is bad because it both misunderstands short-circuit rules in VBA `And`, *and* the ability of Find to locate values in hidden cells depending on exactly how you call it.  Seems like the Excel VBA Find examples have always had bugs of some type.

Comment: @FaneDuru. Yes, thank you, your solution works perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

### Find in an Endless Loop

- This covers the case when you are using the `Find` method (incl. `FIndNext`) to find all occurrences of a value in a range, but you don't want to change them and you also don't want to end up in an endless loop.
- To simplify, the procedures use `Sheet1` (CodeName) and the range "A1:A3" and "Yes" as the criteria.
- Copy them into a new workbook.
- Test first both procedures without values, then put in some "Yes" values (without the double quotes) in the cells. You can also change the range to e.g. `A1:A10`, to better understand.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' To exit the endless loop, press and hold down the ESC key.
Sub testEndlessLoop()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A3")
    Set cel = rng.Find( _
        What:="Yes", _
        After:=rng(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    
    ' Assuring that a cel containing "Yes" has been found. Once it has
    ' been found, find will always find an occurrence of "Yes" whether
    ' there is one, two or three occurrences in the range,
    ' which will result in an endless loop (Do Loop).
    If Not cel Is Nothing Then
        ' A cell containing "Yes" has been found.
        
        Do
            MsgBox "Found ""Yes"" in cell '" & cel.Address & "'."
            ' Find the next occurrence of "Yes"
            Set cel = rng.FindNext(cel)

        ' 'While Not cel Is Nothing' is redundant because 'cel' will
        ' never be 'Nothing' anyway, which is ensured previously with
        ' 'If Not cel Is Nothing Then'.
        Loop While Not cel Is Nothing
    
    Else
        ' A cell containing "Yes" has not been found.
        MsgBox "No occurrences found."
    End If

End Sub

Sub testWorkingLoop()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A3")
    Set cel = rng.Find( _
        What:="Yes", _
        After:=rng(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    
    If Not cel Is Nothing Then
        ' A cell containing "Yes" has been found.

        ' Write the range address of the first found occurrence to a variable.
        FirstAddress = cel.Address
        
        Do
            ' This is where you do stuff when "Yes" is found.
            
            MsgBox "Found ""Yes"" in cell '" & cel.Address & "'."
            ' Most often you don't want to change the found cell,
            ' but you want to change another cell in the same row,
            ' e.g. write to the cell in column 'B'.
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Found a ""Yes""."
            
            ' This is where you do stuff when "Yes" is found.
            
            ' Find the next occurrence of "Yes"
            Set cel = rng.FindNext(cel)
        
        ' Again, 'cel' will never be 'Nothing'.
        Loop While cel.Address <> FirstAddress
    
    Else
        ' A cell containing "Yes" has not been found.
        MsgBox "No occurrences found."
    End If

End Sub
```